# Rails - Configuring defaults for multiple Devise Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have an application that uses multiple user models, each with its own devise configuration and its own model.  For my setup, this made more sense than just using a single user model and roles, and I am happy with how it has all turned out.

However, I am having some issues with devise's defaults and how to override them per model.  For things like unlock_strategy or the time the user has to log in after requesting a password reset , devise looks to the file config/initializers/devise.rb.  How do I set those variables on a per model basis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`#devise`](http://rdoc.info/gems/devise/Devise/Models%3adevise) method in your model accepts a hash of configuration options after the list of modules. Something like:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :lockable, :unlock_strategy => :both
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to get multiple initializer files to play nice - I had no idea it could be that easy!

Comment: Let's say I got User and Client models and I'd like the users to login with the email and the client with their usernames but NOT the email. how would I configure the 'config.authentication_keys' for my client within the devise method?